# python code number_list = [1, 239, 949, 0, 84, 0, 1] output: True number_list = [1, 239, 949, 0, 84, 0, 13] output: False

Tags: python-3.x

This function should return true if the value at the beginning and the end of the list are equal. False otherwise.

Example:

```py
number_list = [1, 239, 949, 0, 84, 0, 1]
```

output:

```py
True
```

```py
number_list = [1, 239, 949, 0, 84, 0, 13]
```

output:

```py
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(list_):
    if list_[0]==list_[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

@Ritika Gupta answered this question
But you can make it shorter by using

```py
def check(l):
    return l[0] == l[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using higher order function.It's clean to do like this sometimes whenever you are passing this function as a comparison function in a sort like function.

Note: In-line lambda statements are mostly slow.

```py
li = [1, 239, 949, 0, 84, 0, 1]
c = lambda x : x[-1]==x[0] #this took 188ns to execute
print(c(li))
```

However, @ritika's and @TranGiaBao's answers are more perform-ant.

```py
def check(l):
    return l[0] == l[-1]

check(l)  #this took 121ns to execute
```